# django custom user field won't appear in admin form

Tags: python, django

I created a custom user model in django with an additional field.
However although I can see it appear in the list view in Django's admin it won't appear in the form to create or update a user, even though I've amended these.

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # Need to support codes with leading 0, hence CharField
     secret = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'secret')


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'secret')
```

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'secret']


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried editing the fieldsets parameter in the CustomUserAdmin class?

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin, ...)
     
    fieldsets = (
        (('User Details'), {'fields': (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
        )}),
        (('Section Title'), {'fields': (
            'field1',
            'field2',
            ...
        )}),
        ...
    )
```

Comment: That kind of works, It will ends up changing the UserChangeForm but not the UserCreationForm. Now found an add_fieldsets property which customises the useraddform.